# DIY PWM Fan Controller; Speed changing too fast

Tags: integrated-circuit, potentiometer, fan, cooling, stripboard

I couldn't think of a way to explain all this in one line, so apologies for the slightly vague title.

I've built a PWM Fan Controller for a DIY Laptop Cooling Pad Project. It theoretically works, and I am able to vary the duty cycle and achieve a change in fan speed from about  10% to a 100%.

However, the fan speed only changes when I rotate my Linear 100K Potentiometer to the half-way mark, and it increases really rapidly afterward. Changing which components, if any, would help make the change in speed slower and smoother?

I built this taking reference from an Overclockers.com forum thread about the same thing: 
http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/641111-Building-PWM-Controller-for-4-wires-PWM-fan?p=6473318&viewfull=1#post6473318
[image: Schematic]

Comment: A log pot connected the right way round?

Comment: A schematic would help, but I'd guarantee that your ancient 741 is causing your trouble. There are 10's, if not 100's, of questions on this stack about the misuse of 741's. Your particular issues are caused by running it from a 5V supply, and expecting it to work with input and output voltages close to the supplies (0V & 5V).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I tried attaching a log pot, but with minimal effect. The speed still changes waay too fast.

Comment: @brhans I've edited my post with a link to where I drew my inspiration from. While their forum thread suggests a 311, I couldn't find one of those, but I did find a 339. Would this solve the issue?

Here's the link to the forum again: http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/641111-Building-PWM-Controller-for-4-wires-PWM-fan?p=6473318&viewfull=1#post6473318

Comment: This is one the most illogical ways to present a problem with layout errors and lack of reference designations. make sure all used inputs are connected.  Like LM431-p2 is a jumpered to a location that goes no where in your diagram.   Use a logic diagram and understand what it does.  Compares average DC from PWM input with average PWM to Fan output. so both must be linear Voltages reduced to a smaller range centred around V+/2  to avoid invalid CM range of Op Amp. DO YOU have a 4 wire fan?

Comment: I indeed do have a 4-wire fan, which is why I can make the observations I did in the OP.
Apologies for the badly drawn up diagram; it was intended for my use only, and admittedly doesn't convey the layout as intended. I shall put up a schematic right now.
As a further update to the post, using a 339 Comparator also yields the same result. What else can I try?

Comment: add ~50k to one side of the pot, so it's like starting half-way turned...